# cronjob for mysqldump is giving error

Tags: mysql, cron

I am using mysqldump command to take backup of my database.

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table -u user -ppassword databasename > backup/mybackup_$(date +%d%m%Y_%H%M).sql
```

and it works fine...But i want to automate this so that it can take a backup once in every two days or something..for this i am using crontab..

```
15 2 * * * mysqldump --add-drop-table -u user -ppassword databasename > backup/mybackup_$(date +%d%m%Y_%H%M).sql
```

but this is giving me an error in putty saying command not found..any idea why??
Please help me..

Answer (score 5):

Use the complete path to `mysqldump`, e.g. `/usr/bin/mysqldump`.

As suggested by the comments, it's a very good idea to use an absolute path for the destination file as well.

Comment: how do i find the complete path??

Comment: `which mysqldump`

Comment: type 'which mysqldump' at a command prompt

Comment: I would use a complete path for the output file, too.